# C# How to force focus to be on my form

Tags: c#, focus

When my form on `c# net3.5` is started and I don't click anywhere, focus remains on my form. But if at the time of loading of a form I click for example on an empty seat of the screen, then focus runs away from my form.

In windows 7 it works, but in windows server 2008 isn't present.

```
private void LoginDialog_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Activate();
}
```

How to force focus to be on my form?

Comment: I've seen people creating workarrounds, switching the form `Topmost` and back.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/80263/How-to-prevent-Form-from-loosing-focus-in-the-appl

Comment: Thank you! I tried , but in windows server 2008 does not work (

Comment: This is by design.  Obvious solutions are not clicking elsewhere and making your UI responsive enough to never give the user a good reason to click elsewhere.